# Unable to get a link class to change on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I have a link within a button that has a class assignment.  The link class dictates color however on hover does not shift as instructed.  Can someone help me find a solution to fix?

Here is the HTML...

```
<div class="row block well" id="section5">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Financing</h1>
  <button class = "button1"><a href="https://form.jotform.com/70176329059157" target="_blank" class="apply">Apply for a Vehicle Loan</a></button>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS...

```
.button1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #b5cfc1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #3d4e3b;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.apply {
  color: #3d4e3b;
}

.apply:hover span{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is **invalid. `button` elements cannot contain `a` elements.** From the specs: *Content model:
    Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.* which `a` belongs to. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0

Comment: Fix you markup first. **Invalid HTML is not acceptable.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button1 {
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 border: 4px solid #b5cfc1;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: #3d4e3b;
}

.button1:hover {
 background-color: #3d4e3b;
 box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 color: #b5cfc1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row block well" id="section5">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Financing</h1>
  <a href="https://form.jotform.com/70176329059157" target="_blank"><button class="button1">Apply for a Vehicle Loan</button></a>  
</div>
```

Luke your answer worked for the coloring but the link was then broken.  After working through it I found a solution that both allows for the link to follow style and still remain functional.  See below...

```
<div class="row block well" id="section5">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Financing</h1>
  <a href="https://form.jotform.com/70176329059157" target="_blank"><button class="button1">Apply for a Vehicle Loan</button></a>  
</div>


.button1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #b5cfc1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #3d4e3b;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #3d4e3b;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    color: #b5cfc1;
}
```

First, I needed to nest the button in the link rather than the other way around.  This allows for the entire button to be a link.  Next, because the button was now nested in the link I could create style for the inner element (button) rather than trying to stylize the parent and than style the child which was causing a conflict. Endless thanks to everyone that contributed to finding a complete solution, unfortunately some answers have been removed so I cannot attribute individually, but it was all instrumental.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```css
.button1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #b5cfc1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button1:hover {
  background-color: #3d4e3b;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.apply {
  color: #3d4e3b;
}
.button1:hover .apply {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row block well" id="section5">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Financing</h1>
  <button class="button1"><a href="https://form.jotform.com/70176329059157" target="_blank" class="apply">Apply for a Vehicle Loan</a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid**. **`button` elements cannot contain `a` elements.** From the specs: *Content model:
    Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.* which `a` belongs to. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0